# Android - Implementing Navigation Drawer in Android 2.2 +

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I wanted to implement the Navigation Drawer given by google at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top.

So, i downloaded the sample from there and used the appcompat library from v7 support library.

Changed extends Activity for MainActivity to extends ActionBarActivity.
And changed everything that was giving error requiring min API Level of 11 to its support library equivalent (  getActionBar() ---> getSupportActionBar(), getFragmentmanger() to getsupportFragmentmanager() )

But now my app is crashing at the first line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in the onCreate() method.

When i try to debug it gives me the error that source not found and opens the   `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1953`

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This example illustrates a common usage of the DrawerLayout widget
 * in the Android support library.
 * <p/>
 * <p>When a navigation (left) drawer is present, the host activity should detect presses of
 * the action bar's Up affordance as a signal to open and close the navigation drawer. The
 * ActionBarDrawerToggle facilitates this behavior.
 * Items within the drawer should fall into one of two categories:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <ul>
 * <li><strong>View switches</strong>. A view switch follows the same basic policies as
 * list or tab navigation in that a view switch does not create navigation history.
 * This pattern should only be used at the root activity of a task, leaving some form
 * of Up navigation active for activities further down the navigation hierarchy.</li>
 * <li><strong>Selective Up</strong>. The drawer allows the user to choose an alternate
 * parent for Up navigation. This allows a user to jump across an app's navigation
 * hierarchy at will. The application should treat this as it treats Up navigation from
 * a different task, replacing the current task stack using TaskStackBuilder or similar.
 * This is the only form of navigation drawer that should be used outside of the root
 * activity of a task.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Right side drawers should be used for actions, not navigation. This follows the pattern
 * established by the Action Bar that navigation should be to the left and actions to the right.
 * An action should be an operation performed on the current contents of the window,
 * for example enabling or disabling a data overlay on top of the current content.</p>
 */
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
04-04 00:46:07.531: D/AndroidRuntime(719): Shutting down VM
04-04 00:46:07.531: W/dalvikvm(719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingmenu/com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
04-04 00:46:07.730: E/AndroidRuntime(719):  ... 11 more
```

**Logcat** after doing changes in manifest

```
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:767)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:321)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  ... 35 more
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark.png from drawable resource ID #0x0
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:327)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  ... 39 more
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark.png
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:405)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365):  ... 42 more
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->


<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

**fragment_planet.xml**

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Theme.AppCompat for theme.

Please update your theme.xml with and set theme in manifest.xml.

theme.xml:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"...
```

I suggest you to forget about Android 2.2 :) No one uses it anymore. And please try to clean project.

You can not use `android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall` under API14 [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textAppearanceListItemSmall).

Comment: Thanks, it helped me but the app is still crashing on Android 2.2 . I have updated the logcat for it. Please help.

Comment: I updated my answer please check it, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have updated my xml files. The files that are giving error in logcat do not exist and i dont see anywhere that they are referenced in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! The `textAppearanceListItemSmall` hint is also very important if you are trying to compile an example using an older API level since Lint won't catch it until you edit your XML file and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your android manifest, are you using the Holo theme or something similar?
Try placing this in your activity tag in the manifest file:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Comment: Yeah it worked and now the app works on Android 4.0 and above. But still crashes on Android 2.2. I have updated the logcat in the ques. Please help.

Comment: Please see the kozaxinan answer, do as he says.

Comment: Check your application manifest and styles.xml for Holo references. This is what is causing the crash:
04-04 00:57:19.443: E/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark.png

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem.
here is my **drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

you can not use these attribute. in Android 2.2

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
```

Comment: Yeah, i have also solved the problem. But thanks anyway.